# starting a next server on cpanel throwing 503 service unavailable

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, cpanel

I'm attempting to deploy a **NextJS** app on my shared hosting server using the **cPanel** *Setup Node.JS App* section, but when I start the build - despite getting `ready on http://localhost:3000` - the site throws a **503** error.

I've uploaded the build folder alongside the `next.config.js`, `package-lock.json`, `package.json` and `server.js` to the application root, and this is my current file structure:

```
next_main
    build (.next folder)
    node_modules
    next.config.js
    package-lock.json
    package.json
    server.js
```

This is my `server.js` file (exactly the same as what Next provided in their custom server docs):

```
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const hostname = "localhost";
const port = 3000;

const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(async (request, response) => {
        try{
            const parsedURL = parse(request.url, true);
            const { pathname, query } = parsedURL;

            switch(pathname){
                case "/a":
                case "/b":
                    await app.render(request, response, pathname, query);
                    break;
                default:
                    await handle(request, response, parsedURL);
            }
        } catch(error){
            console.error("Error occurred.", request.url, error);
            response.statusCode = 500;
            response.end("Internal server error.");
        }
    }).listen(port, error => {
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
    });
}).catch(error => {
    if(error) throw error;
});
```

`Failed to load next.config.js` was also output in my stderr file, despite `next.config.js` being provided.

I've attached the current settings I have applied in my **cPanel**.

*Please note that I do not have root access to the terminal, and am restricted to the `next_main` environment when running any NPM scripts.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it would have solved your exact problem, but I was also getting a 503 error when attempting to setup a new cPanel Node JS app. I discovered that I needed to:

- NOT specify a specific port to run on, but let the OS automatically assign an available port. Somehow cPanel is able to pick this up and send traffic to it.
- Switch the Node JS version. I found out, through trial and error, that only some Node JS versions would actually function via this cPanel setup, while others would fail with a 503 error and no further error information (frustratingly). By switching versions and restarting the app, I eventually found which versions worked and which didn't.
- Be sure that you have your NPM packages installed correctly. You might need to use the button inside cPanel that says <kbd>Run NPM Install</kbd>

If you're still struggling to troubleshoot after that, I would suggest creating a new Node app through the interface, which should create a basic HTTP server script for you. Test that out, and slowly apply commands and packages to the script until you discover which item breaks it.

You can also look for `stderr.log` in your application folder, although this will only show Node JS errors, and not anything from LiteSpeed/Apache or Passenger. I found that many of my 503 errors showed nothing in the log, so it may not be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Checking stderr.log was the key for me. Turns out I couldn't use type:module in my package.json, so removed that line and switched my import statements to require()

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add all environmental variables in the .env file. [add your variable here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlYJw.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).